# Manhattan and Misplaced heuristic

Tags: python, a-star

My apology, I am new to python. Somewhat I managed to work my algorithm but
couldn't do a couple of things with the knowledge that I have with Python. That's why I am here
I need to do three things with my algorithm
1- Need to add Misplaced Tile heuristic function
2 - Need to add Manhattan Distance heuristic function
3 - I need to process val = [0,3,2,5,8,7,1,6,4] instead of start1 = "012634785" a string. How can I do that? Convert string to queue.

Finally, I am trying to write 8 puzzle with A* search
initial state = [0,3,2,5,8,7,1,6,4] something like this.
Final State = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
Please Help me to learn that.
I know its lot to ask for, but I really appreciated y'all.

```
from queue import PriorityQueue
class State(object):
    def __init__ (self, value, parent, start = 0, goal = 0):
        self.children = []
        self.parent = parent
        self.value = value
        self.dist = 0
        if parent:
            self.path = parent.path[:]
            self.path.append(value)
            self.start = parent.start
            self.goal = parent.goal
        else:
            self.path = [value]
            self.start = start
            self.goal = goal

    def GetDist(self):
        pass
    def CreateChildren(self):
        pass

class State_String(State):
    def __init__ (self, value, parent, start = 0, goal = 0):
        super(State_String, self).__init__(value, parent, start, goal)
        self.dist = self.GetDist()
    def GetDist(self):
        if self.value == self.goal:
            return 0
        dist = 0
        for i in range(len(self.goal)):
            letter = self.goal[i]
            dist += abs(i - self.value.index(letter))
        return dist
    def CreateChildren(self):
        if not self.children:
            for i in list(range(len(self.goal)- 1)):
                val = self.value
                val = val[:i] + val[i + 1] + val[i] + val[i + 2:]
                child = State_String(val, self)
                self.children.append(child)

class AStar_Solver:
    def __init__(self, start, goal):
        self.path = []
        self.visitedQueue = []
        self.priorityQueue = PriorityQueue()
        self.start = start
        self.goal = goal

    def Solve(self):
        startState = State_String(self.start, 0, self.start, self.goal)
        count = 0
        self.priorityQueue.put((0, count, startState))
        while (not self.path and self.priorityQueue.qsize()):
            closestChild = self.priorityQueue.get()[2]
            closestChild.CreateChildren()
            self.visitedQueue.append(closestChild.value)
            for child in closestChild.children:
                if child.value not in self.visitedQueue:
                    count += 1
                    if not child.dist:
                        self.path = child.path
                        break
                    self.priorityQueue.put((child.dist, count, child))
        if not self.path:
            print("Goal of ", self.goal, " is not possible")
        return self.path

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start1 = "012634785"
    goal1 = "012345678"
    a = AStar_Solver (start1, goal1)
    a.Solve()
    for i in list(range(len(a.path))):
        print(a.path[i])
```

Comment: Please use this `start1 = [0, 1,2,6,3,4,7,8,5]; start1 = ''.join(str(x) for x in start1); print(start1)` for list to String

Answer (score 2):

If i get what you're asking, you need to take "013749520348" and turn it into a list of integers. To do that:

```
# initial value
string = "012634785"

# converted to integers
list_nums = [int(i) for i in string]

# sort list
list_nums.sort()

# returns
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

If you want answers about something other than this, like the heuristic functions or any of the code you've posted, you need to write a new question that addresses a specific problem you're having and a specific outcome you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Also what you've tried.